# Multiple production environments with multiple configs

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, environment-variables, laravel-7

For the first time I'm making a new web app in Laravel 7 which is going to be deployed on more than one server. Every server has it's own environment variables.

From my previous experiences in Zend framework, all variables were in one config file under some kind of paragraphs. First, there were variables that are common for all environments. After that, every environment have their own overwritten variables. Specific environment was set in index.php and index.php was not deployed. So it's very easy to use and to constantly deploy changes.

My question is, what is the best solution for this purpose in Laravel. So, I need some kind of basic configuration that can be inherited and possibly overwritten in some parts. If there is no something similar, what do you advise me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, configuration inheritance is a tricky thing to do. If you do not have complete overview over the configurations used, you can end up like one of the companies that send a push notification to the wrong users.

Laravel is built in a way where the default configuration can be set in the config folder and overridden using the `.env` file. This is how Laravel is intended to be used, so I suggest doing that.

Or, if you prefer, you can have a folder of `.env` files and then moving the correct one to the root on deployment.

Comment: Actualy I have completely different databases on different servers, so there can be no mixing. I was just trying to find better organization than "moving correct one to the root". By searching it look like there is no some solution for that.

Comment: It's much easier for coding and deploying when you have some kind of inheritance, in this case.

Comment: I don't think there is an out-of-the-box solution to this. If you require inheritance, maybe write an artisan command to generate the configurations? That way you can dynamically construct the right configs.

Comment: thank you for idea, it looks like it's not hard to implement.